# UWP FileIO in use by another process with more than 20,000KB text File

Tags: c#, file-io, uwp, windows-10

I have Problem with FileIO. It continued to error with "in use by another process". below is picture of it.

[image: another process use it, so a process can't access]

so, with lots of debugging .. I found I have problem with "await FileIo.AppendTextAsync()" Part. below is capture of it. if you zoom it, you can see error try-catch on the right-bottom side.
[image: System.IO.FileLoadException]

to solve this problem, I used semaphore to make sure one process can access FileIO -even original source also assure only one process FileIO.- but It didn't work. error again (in use by another process)

below is my source code.

```
    public async Task<List<string>> DoRandom(FileLists fl, StorageFolder folder, StorageFile another_file, int k)
   {
        FileLists retLists = new FileLists();
        List<string> encodingList = new List<string>();

        if (Option1)
        {
            foreach (UploadedFile i in fl)
            {
                await i.setOutFile(folder); // wait until setOutFile ends
                // read stream from storagefile
                using (Stream s = await i.originFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                {
                    // streamreader from stream
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                    {

                        string str = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);

                        string[] vs =
                            str.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None); 

                        foreach (var j in vs)
                        {
                           // try
                            {
                                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(i.outputFile, j); // <--- real Problem Point
                            }
                            //catch { }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and DoRandom function is called by below function.

```
  private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        /** non important source is omitted **/
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();

        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        if (folder != null)
        {
            await myRandomizer.DoRandom(uploadedFileLists, folder, another_file, k);
            /*
            foreach (string str in fileEncoding)
            {
                var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(str);
                messageDialog.Title = str;
                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
            */
        }

    }
}
```

I'm really frustrated because I can't understand what is wrong with my source.
I just made source to operate with a string (split and foreach in those string). In Output File, some strings exist(but not all strings).

and as you can see ,In my source, I have "option1". that means I have some options too. but others are working good. but option1 (with more than20,000KB text File) always make error. what is wrong with my source?

[image: Error Occured]

below is my class and its setOutFile source.

```
class UploadedFile
{
    public StorageFile originFile;
    public StorageFile outputFile { get; set; }
    // ....omitted
   public async Task setOutFile(StorageFolder folder)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        string charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(13);

        for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
        {
            result.Append(charset[rand.Next(charset.Length)]);
        }
        StringBuilder outputName = new StringBuilder();

        outputName.Append(inputName.Substring(0, inputName.Length - 4));
        outputName.Append("_");
        outputName.Append(result);
        outputName.Append(".txt");
        this.outputName = outputName.ToString();

        if (folder != null)
        {
            outputFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(outputName.ToString(), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it your application which is locking the file or is it another application?

Comment: ps: you have a visual studio update pending ;-)

Comment: Your problem may actually be outside your control, like your Antivirus scanning the file, Windows Shadow-Copy, indexing service, etc. Try turning those things off one-by-one until the problem goes away.

Comment: @Stefan thanks for notify me to update vs. I'm not sure that I did lock file. I just createasync StroageFile "outputfile", and make it to my class member variable. and then if option1 is true, then do AppendTextAsync ().

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks, I'll try to find in environmental setting, also.

Comment: Is your semaphoreSlim object is singleton? If it is not, (every Randomizer class generate one of them for themselves), semaphore cannot block file read request.

Comment: if you really can't figure out whats locking the file then you can use winAPI https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283/

Comment: @AdemCatamak Thanks, I solved problem with just upgrade visual studio and rebooting. as you said, I think the problem was some process locked fileIO.

Comment: I am happy for you :) @JeongYoHan

Comment: To help avoid this in the future, especially with AV, don't loop through FileIO.AppendTextAsync - its inefficient and problematic. Instead, append all you text first and then write it to the file with a single call. It'll be much, much faster and help avoid these problems.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Thanks, I changed my source code with your advice. I agreed with your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all your comments. I think The Problem was, as you said & visual studio notify, some process "Locked" FileIO.

actually, I didn't know clearly what is problem that I had, until I met @Johnny Westlake's advice. I did just Upgrad my Visual studio and rebooting my windows. It seemed work good.

so I thought, the previous source code (more older than I posted) made some error on windows, and it ended while it remain some process on.

but It was not true that problem seems to be solved. when I put lots of input File to my App, my App halts again. so, I used try-catch syntax.

finally, I changed my source from "FILEIO.AppendTextAsync" to "FILEIO.WriteTextAsync"(as Johnny Westlake's advice). and with lots of debug, there are no halts, eventually i don't need try-catch syntax.

also Its operation time(Time complexity) costs lower from 10~20 secs to less than 1 secs.(with large file input)

below is my source code.

```
       public async Task<List<string>> DoRandom(FileLists fl, StorageFolder folder, StorageFile another_file, int k)
   {
        FileLists retLists = new FileLists();
        List<string> encodingList = new List<string>();

        if (Option1)
        {
            foreach (UploadedFile i in fl)
            {
                await i.setOutFile(folder); // wait until setOutFile ends
                // read stream from storagefile
                using (Stream s = await i.originFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                {
                    // streamreader from stream
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                    {

                        string str = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
                        List<string> ans = doOption1(stringBuilder, k);
                        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (var j in ans)
                        {
                            ret.Append(j); //<--- append all string
                        }
                        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(i.outputFile, ret.ToString()); // <-- write it at one time
                    }
                }
            }
```